# Don't insert location when device is at one place

Tags: android, location

I'm requesting location in every 5 seconds.

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, GpsStatus.this);
```

I don't want to insert location when device is at 1 place otherwise multiple markers are generating at that place.[Please See Map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DCBt.png). Can anyone please suggest me what I can use. I tried using https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognition but it is not helpful.